# Why is this variable not global (can't use in a function)?

Tags: python

I know I have to use the **global** keyword to access the variable but my question is
why is it not usable inside a function?

```
source = "C:/ALL IN ONE/Test File"
temp = "C:/ALL IN ONE/Temp Folder"
num_files = 0

def sort():
    if not os.path.exists(temp):
        os.makedirs(temp)
        
    for folder_path, folder, files in os.walk(source):
        for file in files:
            num_files += 1   # I can't seem to access the variable "num_files" outside the function
            if file.endswith("txt"):
                pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your variable `global` inside your function like this:

```
num_files = 0

def sort():
    global num_files
    # rest of your code
```

Without declaring it as global, to execute `num_files += 1` which is basically `num_files = num_files + 1`, the function searches for the declaration of an initialised local variable `num_files` to access its value in the right-hand side of your assignment, but there isn't any, hence it raises the `UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment` exception.

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python).

Comment: OHH, Thanks mate!

Comment: If the issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted to close it. @Clorky

Comment: Done! sorry I'm still kinda new to stackoveflow

Comment: No worries. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of the [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp). Your variable `num_files` is actuall in `global` scope, but as soon as you open a function you leave the global scope. In this Situation the variable inside your function is the local variable of your function `sort`. Do receive your variable from the gloabl scope you need the keyword `global` as you already mentioned.